# Dynamoose: how to get the latest rows?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

I'm trying to **get the latest rows of a table**, using [Dynamoose](https://dynamoosejs.com).

I read about `query().ascending()` and `query.descending()`, but I need to query the whole table, which requires the hashkey to be empty, as far as I understood. `scan()` doesn't support sorting.

Something like:

```
MyModel
.scan()                // 1. scan the whole table
.descending('my_date') // 2. sort by descending by a date
.limit(100)            // 3. limit the results to 100
.exec(function(error, data) {
    // return error or data
});
```

Does anyone know how to get the latest rows?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither DynamoDB or Dynamoose API support to get the latest results. You may need to perform this at client side (i.e. write custom code to achieve this result).

**DynamoDB API:-**

The attribute needs to be defined as **SORT key** to sort the data by ascending or descending.

Even **Dynamoose API** doesn't sort the data by all attributes. It sorts the data by sort key only.

- query.descending()  - Sorts the data by sort key attribute of the table in descending order